# XSL FO: Conditional layout based on XML content

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I'm creating a pdf using xsl-fo and antennahouse and I have defined layouts for the first page of my document, odd and even pages using the `fo:simple-page-master` and `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternative` tags based on an xml structure similar to this one:

```
<test>
 <form title="Form A">
  <section title="First Section">
   <item> ... item 1 contents ... </item>
   <item> ... item 2 contents ... </item>
   <item> ... item 3 contents ... </item>
  </section>
  <section title="2nd Section">
   <item> ... item 1 contents ... </item>
   <item> ... item 2 contents ... </item>
   <item> ... item 3 contents ... </item>
  </section>
 </form>
 <form title="Form B">
 </form>
</test>
```

Contents of an item and the item collection itself can be very large, so it can span multiple pages. Anytime a section starts a page break is inserted.

The first page layout has a header that shows the title of the form + the title of the first section centered at the top of the page. The other two layouts have a header with the same info but left-aligned instead of centered.

The question is, is it possible to reuse the first page layout everytime a new section starts? That is, for each section on my document I'd like to have the header centered, while the rest of the pages should still have a header with left-aligned text.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Put each section in a separate `fo:page-sequence`.

It sounds like you're using the form title the same way with each section, so the form title shouldn't be a problem.  Otherwise, you'd have to do something different with the first `fo:page-sequence` to also display the form title.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is not entirely clear what you mean by "reuse".

I'm not aware of a way to put something into an xsl-fo once and use it multiple times, but the advantage of using xslt is that it is easy to produce the xsl-fo "snippet" multiple times in separate `fo:static-content` elements in different `fo:page-sequence`s by the same xslt template (so you have to change only one place).